# Cannot reinstalling igraph

Tags: python, installation, igraph

I installed igraph on my windows server using pip:

```
pip install python_igraph-0.7.1.post6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

After its installation, I could not import it into Spyder (AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph') but I could import and use it in Jupyter Notebook...!!!!
After running some analysis with my graph I wanted to draw it, so I searched trough the net and found [this link](https://gist.github.com/rbnvrw/c2424fe3ff812da892a0) :

[image]

So I thought I should install "cairocffi" and installed it:

```
pip install cairocffi
```

After installing "cairocffi", I couldn't neither draw my graph, nor my igraph package works anymore.

when I imported the igraph again I got the below error:

[image]

I tried uninstalling the igraph, so that I could install it again, but the above error is still there.

So I searched the net to see whether I can download those specified libraries, but found nothing. what should I do?

Comment: python-igraph 0.8.0 is now released. You can consider using it. As for cairocffi, I don't use Windows, so I can't try, but did you read the installation instructions? https://cairocffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for your comment.. since I was in hurry I decided to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda,Python and all packages and libraries, and that workaround solved my problem.